# my data in the console is displayed in the wrong sequence

Tags: c++

Why is my data in the console displayed in the wrong sequence?
I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename T2>
T2 printArr(const T* array, int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        std::cout << array[j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return array[i - 1];
}

int main() {
    const int iSize = 3;

    int i_arr[iSize] = {23, 45, 78};

    std::cout << "Int array: ";
    std::cout << "Last element: " << printArr<int, int>(i_arr, iSize) << std::endl;
}
```

What do I get by compiling it:

```
Int array: 23 45 78 
Last element: 78
```

What should I get in my opinion:

```
Int array: Last element: 23 45 78
78
```

Most likely, I do not understand how the computer that compiles my code thinks.
Here you can see that the result is the same as I described in my question: http://cpp.sh/2lfbcf
And I also try to compile the code in `Visual Studio 2019` and the result is identical

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdc44f4654555785).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++17, given an expression `E1 << E2`, it is **unspecified** whether every value computation and side-effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2.

See [cppreference note 19](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules)

In your code, using a standard before C++17, it is unspecified whether the return value of `printArr()` is calculated (which as a side-effect, streams to `std::cout`) before or after `std::cout << "Last element: "`.